# Repelling a magnet from a coil

Tags: magnetics

I need to suspend an object attached to a magnet over a coil (don't worry about stability problems), and measure the current required to levitate it to a certain height.
There are a number of possible configurations:

- Air core coil with a cylindrical magnet over the coil
- Air core coil with a cylindrical magnet which passes into the coil
- Ferromagnetic core coil with a cylindrical magnet over the coil

The downside of the last one is remanence in the core material, which may distort measurements.
So, do high permeability low (or zero) remanence materials exist?

How do the efficiencies of the first two approaches compare, in terms of current? How much better, if at all, would the third approach be given a typical core material. Frequencies expected to be below 100Hz.

Comment: I'd presume that the less useful a ferric material is as a magnet, the lower its remanence is – steel might be a good tradeoff between still bundling field lines and not exhibiting "magnetic memory". But honestly, air coil sounds fine: the second thing you describes sounds like a normal audio speaker.

Comment: What do you mean by frequency ? Is the permanent magnet not kept at a specific height for a long time ? Wouldn't the coil current be DC ?

Comment: What do you hope to achieve here?  There are probably better ways of weighing something.

Comment: @AJN A PID loop will be used to hold the levitated magnet in a given position. The 100Hz would be the upper frequency of the PID response time

Comment: @ChrisStratton depends what you mean by better. There is a tradeoff between precision and cost

Comment: It's unlikely this kludge will come out cheaper than a scale element where you similarly take responsibility for calibration.  What are you weighing?  What accuracy do you need?

Comment: [This](https://www.quanser.com/products/magnetic-levitation/) (no affiliation) appears to advertise a steel core.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Resolution hoped for is about 1:100,000

Comment: Again, what are you weighing?  For example, 50 grams by milligram is a dirt cheap consumer item, and a lot of the sophistication is in the electronics and algorithm which you'd have to build in your electromagnet case and could re-build in the load cell case.  Don't forget that resolution != accuracy.  When you get into tiny forces, you have to worry about air currents and all sorts of other things, too.

Comment: @ChrisStratton None of it is dirt cheap if you want zero drift over days and good reproducibility. Load cells just don't work that well

Comment: Any system will need frequent re-calibration.  Do you have examples of existing systems which use the technique you are hoping for?   If it's workable it is seems surprising no one is using it.  If someone is using it, what sort of actual coil setup are they using?

Comment: @ChrisStratton It is workable and something similar is used by Shimadzu, Unibloc. BTW, our company makes balances that resolve down to 50ng but will cost you $10k if you want one. The big killer in all these systems is drift, which is why we put them in temperature controlled environments to within 0.1degC. The trick is to do all this cheaply

Comment: So what internal arrangement do these existing systems use?

Comment: FWIW, I've been toying with the idea of weighing lunar tidal forces, and doing a Cavedish with the same setup. This would use a moving magnet, with 99.9% of the levitation force coming from permanent magnets creating a constant with position field, to increase the sensitivity of the control winding, and drop the resonant frequency to mHz. Resistance to stray magnet fields and drift comes from the Moon and the Cavendish mass moving with different periods, resolved with an FFT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think voice coil from a loudspeaker, they've already solved the efficiency problem.

You will have therefore a magnet assembly with an annular gap, with an air-core coil into the gap.

If the coil is a lot longer than the gap, you have good linearity with insertion distance.

With any practical annular gap, the MMF in the magnet will be dominated by the permanent magnet, and little affected by the levitation current.

Now which to have fixed and which moving? If the coil is fixed, then the moving magnet would be very susceptible to forces from stray and varying external magnetic fields, and even moving lumps of ferromagnetic material nearby. A moving coil solves that problem, at the expense of getting current into and out of the moving coil.

Comment: Thanks - this may be the optimum solution. Something to try since this is still in the R&D stage